# Local host for my react app doesn't seems to open ..It loading all the time in my browser

Tags: reactjs

I create a react app ..its run properly on my local host initially but after a break when I came in and run my code on local host again by giving npm start ..its just show loading and loading all the time of my react app in local host..what is the problem? I am totally stack on it..thanks in advance..

Comment: Can you add the exact commands to recreate this that you're running, including all of the output? Does it happen running the app twice in a row? How are you shutting down the app the first time?

Comment: thanks ..I found my error on code ..There a components and code name was same that's why error occurs..I create navbar components and also create navbar from bootstrap ..there is a navbar in the code..#solved